# Total number of ring endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $S=\begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&a \end{pmatrix}:a,b\in R\end{Bmatrix}$. Definitely $f(A)=0$ (zero matrix) and $f(\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&a \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\0&a\end{pmatrix}$ will be two ring endomorphisms of $S$. Is there any other ring endomorphism other than that? Kindly give a hint.

Comment: Your first example is not a ring endomorphism because it does not send the identity to itself.

Comment: $R$ need not contain identity and so does $S$

Comment: What about the identity map?...

Comment: Yes, that is also one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $f: R \to R$ be a ring endomorphism. Then $f$ can be extended to $S$ be setting
$$
f(\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&a \end{pmatrix})=\begin{pmatrix}f(a)&f(b)\\0&f(a)\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let now $R = k[X]$, where $k$ is any field. Then the map $X \to X^2$ can be extended to a ring endomorphism $f$ of $R$ by setting, for each $P \in R$, $f(P) = P(X^2)$. This yields an endomorphism of $S$ which is different from your two examples.

Comment: Pls elaborate a little

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: But if we restrict $R$ to be the ring of integers, then I hope there will be only three endomorphisms of $S$, the two described by me and the identity mapping?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think you should ask it separately. Indeed, if you edit your question now, my answer will become obsolete.

Comment: Ok..I am asking a separate question